# Python class does not have value

Tags: python, linked-list

I am a Javascript engineer and am switching into a JS/Python role. Working on some easy leetcodes to get some quick Python practice.

I'm looking to create a LinkedList here and perhaps I am coming at it from a JS mindset?

Error:
**AttributeError: type object 'LinkedListNode' has no attribute 'value'**

utils.py

```py
# LinkedList Methods

def createLinkedList(arr):
    head = createLinkedListNode(None, arr.pop(0))

    def populateList(arr, prevNode):
        if arr:
            node = createLinkedListNode(None, arr.pop(0))
            prevNode.next = node
            if arr:
                populateList(arr, node)

    populateList(arr, head)

    return head

def createLinkedListNode(next, value):
    class LinkedListNode:
        def __init__(self):
            self.next = next
            self.value = value

    return LinkedListNode
```

deleteNode.py

```py
from python.utils import createLinkedList, linkedListToArray

useCase1 = [4, 5, 1, 9]

linkedList = createLinkedList(useCase1)
```

^ linkedList.value doesn't exist?

Comment: you are indeed close to "not even wrong".  "classes" are not "structures", and even if they were, they should be declared just once, there is no sense in creating a new class each time you call a function.
Also, the class creates its own instance, and will anotate its parameters in the `__init__` method: there is zero need for a factory function to create an instance. (much less create a new class for each call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some misunderstandings with python classes:

1. The class `LinkedListNode` should not defined in function.
2. Return `LinkedListNode` is actually returning the class itself, but not the *Instance*. To return the instance, you have to **call** the class. `return LinkedListNode()`
3. Using next as instance variable is not ideal. next is an iteration function in python, so when you set `self.next = next`, you are actually assigning the function to `self.next`
4. If you want to set a variable, for example `self.next_value = next_value`, you should put next_value as a parameter of `__init__` function, like `def __init__(self, next_value)`

Here is a simple demo of Linked List:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next_value = None

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.value
        if self.next_value is not None:
            yield from self.next_value
        # else raise StopIteration

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index == 0:
            return self.value
        else:
            return self.next_value[index-1]
            # recursively get the next value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value) + ' -> ' + str(self.next_value)

    def __len__(self):
        if self.next_value is None:
            return 1
        else:
            return 1 + len(self.next_value)
            # recursively get the length

    def append(self, value):
        if self.next_value is None:
            self.next_value = LinkedList(value, self)
        else:
            self.next_value.append(value)

a = LinkedList(2)
a.append(1)
a.append(3)

for num in a:
    print(num, end=", ")

print()

print(a[1])
print(a)
print(len(a))
```

Output:

```
2, 1, 3, 
1
2 -> 1 -> 3 -> None
3
```

Comment: Ah yes thank you I forgot to instanciate it. Interesting thing about the next bit that would definitely have tripped me up.

Answer (score 0):

`createLinkedListNode()` returns the `LinkedListNode` class itself, not an *instance* of the class.

Why are you defining classes and functions inside of other functions?  That's an odd way of doing things.

Comment: As a frontend js dev most of the work I do could be labeled functional programming. In that regard you will find times in which there are functions in functions. It's mainly for scoping to keep the global namespace clean. I have to look more into "Classes" in Python.